# Defining a function from lists to binary and unary trees

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, binary-tree

Consider binary and unary trees, as defined by the following type, and a function `flatten`, which converts binary and unary trees to lists (e.g, `flatten (Node (Leaf 10) 11 (Leaf 20))` is `[10,11,20]`):

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | UNode a (Tree a) deriving (Show)
flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten (Leaf x) = [x] 
flatten (Node l x r) = flatten l ++ [x] ++ flatten r
flatten (UNode l x) = [l] ++ flatten x
```

I am trying to define a recursive function, `reverseflatten`, which converts lists to binary and unary trees, specifically *in the manner of the following pattern*, which works for lists of length <= 7. I can see how the pattern would go on, but not how to create a recursive function from my example:

```
reverseflatten :: [a] -> Tree a
reverseflatten [x] = (Leaf x)
reverseflatten [x,y] = UNode x (Leaf y)
reverseflatten [x,y,z] = Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)
reverseflatten [x,y,z,x'] = Node (Leaf x) y (UNode z (Leaf x') )
reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y'] = Node (Leaf x) y ( Node (Leaf x') z (Leaf y'))
reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y',z'] =  Node (Leaf x) y ( Node (Leaf x') z ( UNode y' (Leaf z')))
reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y',z',x''] =  Node (Leaf x) y ( Node (Leaf x') z ( Node (Leaf z') y' (Leaf x'')))
```

How would I create such a recursive function, that for any finite list, forms a binary tree of the kind defined above? The answer below does not do this, since it does not follow the pattern above.

---

Edit: 
The procedure I followed for even lists > 2, should be fairly transparent (you take the tree corresponding to an odd list and then you add a unary node).
The general procedure I followed for constructing a tree from an odd-numbered list was this. `reverse flatten[x,y,z]` is `Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)`. Then for the next odd-numbered list up, `[x, y, z, x', y']`, I wanted to preserve `z` in its previous position in the case for `reverseflatten [x,y,z]` (in which `z` was the final bottom right leaf), and so position `z` as in `Node (Leaf x') z (Leaf y')`, in the second place, so that the tree for this case is just like the tree for `reverseflatten [x,y,z]`, except that we add nodes surrounding the bottom right leaf, `z`. I then wanted x' and y' to surround `z`, in the order in which they are present in the list, hence Node (Leaf x') z (Leaf y').
 Then for the next odd-numbered list `reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y',z',x'']` , I had a similar idea in mind. I wanted `y'` to remain in its place in `reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y']` and `reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y',z', x'']`) to be constructed by surrounding `y'` by z' and x'', in the order in which they are present in the list.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: then it is really a unary tree, consisting of a mother node, and a single daughter node, which is a leaf. I will edit my question.

Comment: I've only had a brief look, but I'm not quite sure of what the recursive pattern is here. It's the same *shape* as `reverseFlatten (x:y:xs) = Node (Leaf x) y (reverseFlatten xs)` I think (with the singleton and 2-element list cases explicitly as you have them above), but the precise way the list elements are assigned to nodes or leaves seems strange. Can you explain the thought process in words? [Doing so will probably take you a long way towards getting the right recursive definition.]

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: We form `Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)` from  `[x,y,z]`, and then  `Node (Leaf x) y (UNode z (Leaf x') )` from `[x,y,z,x']`. Then for `[x, y, z, x', y'] I wanted to preserve `z` in its previous position in the case for `reverseflatten [x,y,z]`, and so position `z` as in `Node (Leaf x') z (Leaf y')`, in the second place. I then wanted `x'` and `y'` to be the daughters of `z`, in the order in which they are present in the list, hence `Node (Leaf x') z (Leaf y')`.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond:  Then for `reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y',z',x'']` I had a similar idea in mind (I wanted `y'`' to remain a mother node (as it is in the case `reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y']` and `reverseflatten [x,y,z,x',y',z']`) , with daughters `z'` and `x'`)

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: So the general idea is that whenever the list is odd, we preserve the tree as it was for the previous odd numbered list, but add two daughters: one daughter to the bottom left of the final rightmost element of the tree corresponding to the previous odd numbered list, and the other daughter to the bottom right.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation. Unfortunately I'm about to go to bed and don't want to think too hard about it now - I expect someone else will have posted an answer by the time I wake up, but if not I'll return to it.

Comment: @user65526 can you check my edited code in the answer ?

Comment: @Koralp Catalsakal: That's it :) ! It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to change the code to capture the pattern you were asking for. My implementation is not very efficient, but could not think of any at the moment. 
I hope that I understood the pattern correctly.

```
reverseflatten :: [a] -> Tree a
reverseflatten [x] = (Leaf x)
reverseflatten [x,y] = UNode x (Leaf y)
reverseflatten [x,y,z] = Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)
reverseflatten (x:y:xs) = revflat2 (x:y:xs)

revflat2 :: [a] -> Tree a
revflat2 [x] = (Leaf x)
revflat2 [x,y] = UNode y (Leaf x)
revflat2 [x,y,z] = Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)
revflat2 (x:y:xs) = Node (Leaf x) y (revflat2 ([head $ tail xs] ++ [head xs] ++ tail (tail xs)))
```

Comment: @Koralp Catalsakal: This doesn't quite generate the pattern I wanted (see my comment to Robin Zigmond)

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: Yes, I had wanted it to be as in my example. So how do I modify the above to account for that? For example, I want a list `[1..5]` to go to `Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 4) 3 (Leaf 5))` and `[1..7]` to go to `Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 4) 3 (Node (Leaf 6) 5 (Leaf 7)))`.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: written a response above :)

Comment: @Koralp Catalsakal: Also, at the moment `reverseflatten [1..5]` is `Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 4) 3 (Leaf 5)`, but `(reverseflatten(flatten(reverseflatten [1..5])))` does not return `reverseflatten [1..5]`, which is what would be ideal. How could `flatten` be modified so that `reverseflatten x: xs` is `(reverseflatten(flatten(reverseflatten x:xs)))`?

Comment: @user65526 In `reverseflatten`, we switch the ordering of the array. For example, for the input of [1,2,3,4,5] our `reverseflatten` gives an output of [1,2,4,3,5]. However, the `flatten` function does not capture this and assumes the ordering of the array is the order of the tree. Therefore, to be able to use `flatten` correctly, you will need to reverse the switching operation in `reverseflatten`. I can't currently work on it, but will try if I have the time :)