# Flattening a binary tree in a specific manner

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, binary-tree

Consider the following definitions of binary and unary trees, a function `flatten`, which converts binary and unary trees to lists (e.g, `flatten (Node (Leaf 10) 11 (Leaf 20))` is `[10,11,20]`) and a function, `reverseflatten`, which converts lists to binary trees (*in the specific manner described here ([Defining a function from lists to binary and unary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738406/defining-a-function-from-lists-to-binary-and-unary-trees/54738585#54738585)) and illustrated in the picture below*):

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | UNode a (Tree a) deriving (Show)
flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten (Leaf x) = [x] 
flatten (Node l x r) = flatten l ++ [x] ++ flatten r
flatten (UNode l x) = [l] ++ flatten x

reverseflatten :: [a] -> Tree a
reverseflatten [x] = (Leaf x)
reverseflatten [x,y] = UNode x (Leaf y)
reverseflatten [x,y,z] = Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)
reverseflatten (x:y:xs) = revflat2 (x:y:xs)

revflat2 :: [a] -> Tree a
revflat2 [x] = (Leaf x)
revflat2 [x,y] = UNode y (Leaf x)
revflat2 [x,y,z] = Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)
revflat2 (x:y:xs) = Node (Leaf x) y (revflat2 ([head $ tail xs] ++ [head xs] ++ tail (tail xs)))
```

`reverseflatten [1..5]` is `Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 4) 3 (Leaf 5)`, but `(reverseflatten(flatten(reverseflatten [1..5])))` does not return the same as `reverseflatten [1..5]`. How could `flatten` be modified so that `reverseflatten x: xs` is the same as `(reverseflatten(flatten(reverseflatten x:xs)))`?

`reverseflatten` forms the series of trees in the picture below. 
For example, `reverseflatten [x,y,z]` forms Tree 2 in the picture, `reverseflatten [x,y,z, x']` forms Tree 3, `reverseflatten [x,y,z, x', y']` forms Tree 4, `reverseflatten [x,y,z, x', y', z']` forms Tree 5, `reverseflatten [x,y,z, x', y', z', x'']` forms Tree 6, etcetera.
[image: Series of trees generated by <code>reverseflatten</code>]

What I want is that `reverseflatten x: xs` is the same as `(reverseflatten(flatten(reverseflatten x:xs)))`. So I need to design `flatten` so it has this effect.

I have made the following attempt (where the case `flatten Node l x r` is supposed to divide into a case in which `r` is a leaf, and a case where it is not):

```
flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten (Leaf x) = [x] 
flatten (UNode l x) = [l] ++ flatten x 
flatten (Node l x r)
    | r == Leaf y   = [l, x, r]  
    | otherwise = flatten (Node l x (revflat2 ([head $ tail r] ++ [head r]     ++ tail (tail r)))
```

but this produces:

```
experiment.hs:585:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
    |
585 | flatten (UNode l x) = [l] ++ flatten x 
    | ^
```

Comment: first simplify the problem - the real issue is that `flatten $ reverseflatten [1..5]` is not equal to `[1..5]`, which you clearly intend it to be. (Since Haskell is referentially transparent, applying `reverseflatten` to each side would produce the same result if they were equal.) (I don't know how to solve this, although it's related to your rather complicated and un-natural recipe for "reverse flattening", but just saying that it will be simpler to consider the root problem rather than a consequence of it.)

Comment: @Robin Zigmond: Can I (politely) beg to differ on it being unnatural? In natural language syntax and semantics (my field) the recipe I devised is actually very natural :) Granted, it may be unnatural from other perspectives, and perhaps to where you are coming from...

Comment: Fair enough, it's a matter of opinion, I'll clarify my first comment to reflect that. Well apparently I can't edit the comment any more, but hopefully this will do for clarification. What I really meant, anyway, is that you can't express it with a simple 2/3 line recursive definition and instead ended up needing an auxiliary function, with both functions having 4 cases.

Comment: You took the `reverseflatten` from the answer to your previous post, which appears to be buggy. Is that answer actually correct, or should we still take your previous description as the reference?

At the moment there is only a very informal description of the structure you want, which as we all know is highly prone to misinterpretation. Some context about where that comes from, what it means in your domain, would help clarify the situation.

Comment: If you expect `reverseflatten (flatten (reverseflatten xs)))` to always be true, presumably your code is based on some data structure description that includes a proof for this property holding. You should check your implementation line by line if it actually does what is required from the definition of your operators.

Comment: @Li-yao Xia: Please see the edited question.

Comment: Ok sorry I was mistaken about the status of `reverseflatten`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is that the first node of the tree does not have the same pattern as the others, as in if you look at Tree1 it goes [x,y,z] , whereas Tree4 goes [x,y,[x',z,y']].

You can see that the ordering of the child nodes do not follow that of the first one, which is why some people noted it feels un-natural. To fix it you can either change your definition of reverseFlattening to one that has a constant pattern, which I assume you don't want, or change your flatten to take this weird pattern into account:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | UNode a (Tree a) deriving (Show)

reverseFlatten :: [a] -> Tree a
reverseFlatten [x] = (Leaf x)
reverseFlatten [x,y] = UNode y (Leaf x)
reverseFlatten [x,y,z] = Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)
reverseFlatten (x:y:xs) = Node (Leaf x) y (reverseFlatten ((xs !! 1) : (head xs) : (drop 2 xs)))

flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten (Leaf x)            = [x]
flatten (UNode l (Leaf x))  = [l,x]
flatten (Node (Leaf l) x r) = l : x : flattenRest r

flattenRest :: Tree a -> [a]
flattenRest (Leaf x)            = [x]
flattenRest (UNode l (Leaf x))  = [l,x]
flattenRest (Node (Leaf l) x r) = x : l : flattenRest r
```

Note that I extended the pattern matching for your UNode and the left Node as you know already it will be a left-sided tree so there's no need to call your function if you know already what the result will be.

Comment: That's it! :) These functions are very natural for my purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

### Testable specification

First we can implement your specification `reverseflatten (flatten (reverseflatten (x : xs))) = reverseflatten (x : xs)` as a QuickCheck property.

- We parameterize it by `flatten` and `reverseflatten` so it is easy to plug in different implementations.
- We specialize the element type to `Int` because we have to tell QuickCheck what to generate at some point.
- The type variable `a` really means `Tree Int`, but the generality will be useful later.

```
import Test.QuickCheck

prop_flat :: (Eq a, Show a) =>
             (a -> [Int]) -> ([Int] -> a) -> (Int, [Int]) -> Property
prop_flat f rf (x0, xs0) =
    (rf . f . rf) xs === rf xs
  where
    xs = x0 : xs0

-- Also remember to derive both Show and Eq on Tree.
```

We can check that it's a nontrivial property by applying it to the incorrect implementation.

```
ghci> quickCheck $ prop_flat flatten reverseflatten
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 5 tests and 8 shrinks):    
(0,[0,0,1,0])
Node (Leaf 0) 0 (Node (Leaf 0) 1 (Leaf 0)) /= Node (Leaf 0) 0 (Node (Leaf 1) 0 (Leaf 0))
```

### Flatten, first take

Now the implementation of `flatten` needs to be split in two stages, like `reverseflatten`, because the root behaves differently from the other nodes:

- at the root, `Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)` → `[x, y, z]`,
- but in the inner nodes, `Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)` → `[y, x, z]`

Also note that all the trees you've shown, and those that can actually be generated by `reverseflatten` lean to the right, so we really only know what to do on patterns `Leaf x`, `UNode x (Leaf y)` and `Node (Leaf x) y r`, but not other patterns like `UNode x (Node ...)` or `Node (Node ...) y r`. Hence, considering the whole domain of `Tree`s, `flatten1` is highly partial:

```
flatten1 :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten1 (Leaf x) = [x]
flatten1 (UNode x (Leaf y)) = [x, y]
flatten1 (Node (Leaf x) y r) = x : y : flatten1' r

flatten1' :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten1' (Leaf x) = [x]
flatten1' (UNode x (Leaf y)) = [x, y]
flatten1' (Node (Leaf y) x r) = x : y : flatten1' r
```

Partiality notwithstanding, QuickCheck agrees:

```
ghci> quickCheck $ prop_flat flatten1 reverseflatten
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

### Flatten, total version

A total function can be obtained by generalizing the patterns a bit, but as the test above shows, the specification does not cover these extra cases. Whenever we pattern match on a nested `Leaf y`, we instead just get the whole tree `ys` and flatten it. If it does turn out to be `ys = Leaf y`, then it will be flattened to a singleton list, so the original semantics are preserved.

```
flatten2 :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten2 (Leaf x) = [x]
flatten2 (UNode x ys) = x : flatten2 ys
flatten2 (Node xs y r) = flatten2 xs ++ y : flatten2' r

flatten2' :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten2' (Leaf x) = [x]
flatten2' (UNode x ys) = x : flatten2' ys
flatten2' (Node ys x r) = x : flatten2' ys ++ flatten2' r
```

### Flatten, totally specified version

Rather than arbitrarily generalizing the function on the unspecified part of its domain, we can also restrict its domain to match exactly the specification. This leads to an alternative type definition: in all examples, `UNode` only has a leaf subtree, and similarly `Node` has only a leaf as the left subtree, so we unpack those leaves into the constructors.

```
data Tree' a = Leaf' a | UNode' a a | Node' a a (Tree' a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The implementation of `flatten'` is a straightforward adaptation of `flatten1`:

```
flatten' :: Tree' a -> [a]
flatten' (Leaf' x) = [x]
flatten' (UNode' x y) = [x, y]
flatten' (Node' x y r) = x : y : f'' r

f'' :: Tree' a -> [a]
f'' (Leaf' x) = [x]
f'' (UNode' x y) = [x, y]
f'' (Node' x y r) = y : x : f'' r
```

`reverseflatten'` is similarly adapted from a refactored version of `reverseflatten`.

```
reverseflatten' :: [a] -> Tree' a
reverseflatten' (x : []) = Leaf' x
reverseflatten' (x : y : []) = UNode' x y
reverseflatten' (x : y : z : r) = Node' x y (rf'' z r)

rf'' :: a -> [a] -> Tree' a
rf'' x [] = Leaf' x
rf'' x (y : []) = UNode' x y
rf'' x (y : z : r) = Node' y x (rf'' z r)
```

QuickCheck validates:

```
ghci> quickCheck $ prop_flat flatten' reverseflatten'
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's hypothesize a slightly stronger property and just calculate without thinking, and see where it gets us. Namely, that stronger property will be that whenever `xs` is not empty, we have:

```
flatten (reverseflatten xs) = xs
```

From the definition of `reverseflatten`, there are four cases to consider. The first is this:

```
flatten (reverseflatten [x]) = [x]
flatten (Leaf x) = [x]
```

Next:

```
flatten (reverseflatten [x,y]) = [x,y]
flatten (UNode x (Leaf y)) = [x,y]
```

Then:

```
flatten (reverseflatten [x,y,z]) = [x,y,z]
flatten (Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)) = [x,y,z]
```

Finally:

```
flatten (reverseflatten (x:y:xs)) = x:y:xs
flatten (revflat2 (x:y:xs)) = x:y:xs
```

Because the previous patterns have captured the situations where `xs` matches `[]` or `[_]`, we need only consider one case of `revflat2`, namely, the one where `xs` has at least two elements.

```
flatten (revflat2 (x:y:w:z:xs)) = x:y:w:z:xs
flatten (Node (Leaf x) y (revflat2 (z:w:xs))) = x:y:w:z:xs
```

Aha! For this to work, it would be nice to have a helper with a new property, namely:

```
flatten2 (revflat2 (z:w:xs)) = w:z:xs
```

(We'll actually use the names `x` and `y` instead of `w` and `z`, of course.)
Once again let us calculate without thinking. There are three cases for `xs`, namely `[]`, `[_]`, and longer. When `xs` is `[]`:

```
flatten2 (revflat2 [x,y]) = [y,x]
flatten2 (UNode y (Leaf x)) = [y,x]
```

For `[_]`:

```
flatten2 (revflat2 [x,y,z]) = [y,x,z]
flatten2 (Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)) = [y,x,z]
```

And for longer:

```
flatten2 (revflat2 (x:y:w:z:xs)) = y:x:w:z:xs
flatten2 (Node (Leaf x) y (revflat2 (z:w:xs))) = y:x:w:z:xs
```

By induction hypothesis, we have `flatten2 (revflat2 (z:w:xs)) = w:z:xs`, so this last equation can become:

```
flatten2 (Node (Leaf x) y rest) = y:x:flatten2 rest
```

Now we can just take all the final lines of each of these cases and they make a program:

```
flatten (Leaf x) = [x]
flatten (UNode x (Leaf y)) = [x,y]
flatten (Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)) = [x,y,z]
flatten (Node (Leaf x) y rest) = x:y:flatten2 rest

flatten2 (UNode y (Leaf x)) = [y,x]
flatten2 (Node (Leaf x) y (Leaf z)) = [y,x,z]
flatten2 (Node (Leaf x) y rest) = y:x:flatten2 rest
```

Is this the best program? No! In particular, it's partial -- you have some free choices you can make about what `flatten` and `flatten2` should do when the first tree argument to a `Node` or `UNode` is not a `Leaf` (but no matter what choice you make it will not affect the property you care about) and about what `flatten2` should do with leaves. Likely if you make sane choices here, you can coalesce many of the patterns.

But what's nice about this process is that it's *completely* mechanical: you can take your property of interest, turn a crank, and get out a function with that property (or conflicting equations that tell you it's not possible and why). Only once you have something that works do you need to stare and think about what would make it prettier or better. Yay, equational reasoning!